# Общая сессия для Wordpress и микросайта на PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, сессия

На данный момент на хостинге установлен Wordpress, туда же планируется установить микроприложение далее МП на Slim, Codeigniter или на чистом PHP. Нужно сделать так, чтобы пользователя аутентифицированного через админку Wordpress МП также воспринимало как аутентифицированного.

Отсюда два вопроса.

1. Если Wordpress и МП будут жить на одном домене, сможет ли МП перехватывать значения сессии Wordpress через **$_SESSION['some_name'];**?
2. А если МП будет на субдомене ?

Comment: $_SESSION - суперглобальная переменная php. А php - он и в Африке php. проблема лишь в том, что WP не использует сессии, только куки ).

Comment: Для работы сторонних приложений с ВП нужно использовать REST API https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/

Comment: Я пошел таким путем. Поскольку приложение и Wordpress сидят на одном хостинге, то и доступ к одной БД имеют. Я в приложении беру $_COOKIE и проверяю его ключи на наличе подстроки "wordpress_logged_in_". Потом из значения этого ключа выдергиваю имя пользователя и по нему в базе нахожу его права и дальше действую соответствующим образом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По некотором размышлении мне пришла в голову следующая идея. Т.к. Wordpress и мое приложение находятся на одном хостинге в соседних директориях, то ни что не мешает мне воспользоваться API самого Wordpress'а.

```
require dirname(__FILE__) . '/../wp-load.php';

echo '<pre>';        
print_r(wp_get_current_user());
echo '</pre>';
```